# Real and Imaginary parts of DiGamma function.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

For the digamma function defined by
\begin{equation}
\psi^0(z)=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d z}\ln \Gamma(z);\quad z\in \mathbb{C}=Z_\Re+ i Z_\Im.
\end{equation}
where $\Gamma(z)=\int_0^\infty \mathrm d x e^{-x} x^{z-1}$ is the Gamma function.

If there a way to write down an closed form expression for $\Re \psi^0(z) $ and $\Im \psi^0(z) $?

Looking at the integral representations like
\begin{equation}
\psi^0(z)=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{t (-z)}}{1-e^{-t}}\right) \, dt
\end{equation}
and others it looks like I can't separate out the real and imaginary part.

Are there any other series representation where this is possible? Or are there some other tricks that I can use?

Comment: $\Re(\psi^{(0)}(z))=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi^{(0)}(z)+\psi^{(0)}\left(z^*\right)\right)$ and $\Im(\psi^{(0)}(z))=-\frac{i}{2} \left(\psi^{(0)}(z)-\psi^{(0)}\left(z^*\right)\right)$ where $^∗$ is the complex conjugate.

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something, but can you not write

$e^{t (-z)}= e^{-t Z_\Re}\cos (t \: Z_\Im) - i \: e^{-t Z_\Re} \sin(t \: Z_\Im )$ ?

Hence
$$\psi^0(z)=\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-t Z_\Re}\cos (t \: Z_\Im)}{1-e^{-t}}\right) dt $$
$$ + \, i  \int_0^{\infty}  \left( \frac{\: e^{-t Z_\Re} \sin(t \: Z_\Im )}{1-e^{-t}}\right)dt $$

This gives a closed integral expressions for the real and imaginary parts or were you looking for another form for the separation?